Concatenate with multiple values in order
I have a question about SQL Server 2008: how to concatenate with comma (,) for multiple columns with orders of columns?
Table timeschedule:
Id |  Name | days |daysfrequency|scheduletime
---+-------+------+-------------+------------
1  |  a    |Day4  |Monthly      |22:10
1  |  a    |Thu   |Weekly       |07:30
1  |  a    |Fri   |Daily        |23:10
2  |  b    |Mon   |Weekly       |20:00
2  |  b    |Tue   |Weekly       |23:10
2  |  b    |Wed   |Weekly       |18:10
2  |  b    |Thu   |Weekly       |10:23
2  |  b    |Fri   |Weekly       |1:23

Based on this data, I need an output like this:
id | Name  | Days              |DaysFrequency        | ScheduleTIme
---+-------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------
1  |a      |Days4,THu,Fri      |Monthly,Weekly,Daily |22:10,07:30,23:10
2  |b      |Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri|Weekly               |20:00,23:10,18:10,10:23,1:23

I have tried with this SQL:
select 
    id, name,
    Days = stuff((select distinct ',' days 
                  from timeschedule t
                  where t.id = t1.id and t.name = t1.name
                  for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),
    daysfrequency = stuff((select distinct ',' daysfrequency 
                           from timeschedule t
                           where t.id = t1.id and t.name = t1.name
                           for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),
    scheduletime = stuff((select distinct ',' scheduletime 
                          from timeschedule t
                          where t.id = t1.id and t.name = t1.name
                          for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from 
    timeschedule t1 
group by 
    id, name

Using this query it is not return the expected order in the days, daysfrequenc, scheduletime output columns.
Could someone please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server 2008?

What is the logic behind the ordering?

You need another column in the table to determine the required ordering

Upgrade this very obsolete version and then use STRING_AGG

Does this answer your question? String_agg for SQL Server before 2017

This stuff will never work properly in a real world. Let's say you have another schedule for Weekly Fri. How are you gonna display that? The "helpful" schedule table is just a recipe for a misleading one.

Please try the following solution(s).
As correctly mentioned by @Squirrel:

You need another column in the table to determine the required
ordering

SQL #1
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT, _name CHAR(1), days VARCHAR(10), daysfrequency VARCHAR(10), scheduletime VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl (id,_name,days,daysfrequency,scheduletime) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'Day4','Monthly','22:10'),
(1, 'a', 'Thu', 'Weekly', '07:30'),
(1, 'a', 'Fri', 'Daily',  '23:10'),
(2, 'b', 'Mon', 'Weekly', '20:00'),
(2, 'b', 'Tue', 'Weekly', '23:10'),
(2, 'b', 'Wed', 'Weekly', '18:10'),
(2, 'b', 'Thu', 'Weekly', '10:23'),
(2, 'b', 'Fri', 'Weekly', '1:23');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
SELECT id, _name 
    , Days=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + days 
    FROM @tbl t
    WHERE t.id=t1.id and t._name=t1._name
    FOR xml path('')),1,1,'')
    , daysfrequency=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + daysfrequency 
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE t.id=t1.id and t._name=t1._name
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    , scheduletime=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + scheduletime 
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE t.id=t1.id and t._name=t1._name
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM @tbl AS t1 
GROUP BY id,_name;

Output



id
_name
Days
daysfrequency
scheduletime




1
a
Day4,Fri,Thu
Daily ,Monthly,Weekly
07:30,22:10,23:10


2
b
Fri,Mon,Thu,Tue,Wed
Weekly
1:23,10:23,18:10,20:00,23:10



SQL #2
-- Method #2
-- pure XQuery
-- different sort order within columns in comparison with Method #1
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT id, _name
, (SELECT days FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE t.id=t1.id AND t._name=t1._name
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('
       for $i in /root/days
       return if ($i is (/root/days[last()])[1]) then string($i)
                    else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))
').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Days
, (SELECT DISTINCT daysfrequency FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE t.id=t1.id AND t._name=t1._name
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('
       for $i in /root/daysfrequency
       return if ($i is (/root/daysfrequency[last()])[1]) then string($i)
                    else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))
').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS daysfrequency
, (SELECT scheduletime FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE t.id=t1.id AND t._name=t1._name
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('
       for $i in /root/scheduletime
       return if ($i is (/root/scheduletime[last()])[1]) then string($i)
                    else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))
').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS scheduletime
FROM @tbl AS t1 
GROUP BY id,_name;

Output



id
_name
days
daysfrequency
scheduletime




1
a
Day4, Thu, Fri
Daily, Monthly, Weekly
22:10, 07:30, 23:10


2
b
Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
Weekly
20:00, 23:10, 18:10, 10:23, 1:23




id | Name  | Days              |DaysFrequency        | ScheduleTIme
---+-------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------
1  |a      |Days4,THu,Fri      |Monthly,Weekly,Daily |22:10,07:30,23:10
2  |b      |Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri|Weekly               |20:00,23:10,18:10,10:23,1:23
I am expecting above format but in day frequency ,schedutime geeing differnt order

id:1 days should be come Day4,Thu,Fri and DayFrequency : Monthly,Weekly,Daily, schedultime : 22:10,07:30,23:10

You need one more missing column in the table to determine the required ordering. By default it is an unordered set.

I adjusted the answer. Please try now SQL #2
